# VS Code auto completion for PHP and Wordpress

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently discovered VS Code and while I like it a lot I can't find a way to achieve auto completion like I am used to with Sublime Text 3 for example.

```
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => '4',
        'post_type' => 'review',
        'orderby'   => 'the_title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    );
```

I am used to have auto completion offers for all those values in the array but no matter what I try, with VS Code I can't get those. Is there a way to enable auto completion for those values or is it just not possible with VS Code? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Two extensions that you can give a try, that will help with auto completion

- [PHP Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-intellisense)

> Advanced Autocompletion and Refactoring support for PHP

- [PHP-Autocomplete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bschulte.php-autocomplete)

which is a...

> ...very basic autocomplete extension for PHP. It's meant to allow for suggestions of functions that have been declared in separate PHP files included in the current document through include/require statements. The purpose of this is to be able to get autocomplete for functions that are not part of a class structure.

If all else fails, you can [Create your own Snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets)

> Code snippets are templates that make it easier to enter repeating code patterns, such as loops or conditional-statements.
>
> Snippets show in IntelliSense (`Ctrl+Space`) mixed with other suggestions as well as in a dedicated snippet picker (**Insert Snippet** in the Command Palette). There is also support for tab-completion: Enable it with `"editor.tabCompletion": true`, type a *snippet prefix*, and press `Tab` to insert a snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I did use Intellisense already and just gave PHP-Autocomplete a try but that did not help.

Comment: @Alex8472 you should have mentioned what you had already tried (in your question), then :) Take a look at my updated answer...